# How to Send a Message on Bot Startup

Tags: java, discord-jda

Currently I'm making a bot that would remind me every Thursday at 1:00PM. The timer part is already finished but I need it to initialize on bot startup. I'm using GuildMessageReceivedEvent and activating it by doing a command. I've tried ReadyEvent but I can't send messages using that event. Any help is appreciated.

Code:

```
public class Reminder extends ListenerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void onGuildMessageReceived(GuildMessageReceivedEvent e) {
        String[] args = e.getMessage().getContentRaw().split("\\s+");
        if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("!start")) {
            if (e.getGuild().getId().equalsIgnoreCase("679875946597056683")) {
                TextChannel defaultChannel = e.getGuild().getDefaultChannel();
                if (defaultChannel != null) {
                    e.getChannel().sendTyping().queue();
                    e.getChannel().sendMessage("Reminder has been activated.").queue();
                    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles"));
                    LocalDateTime then = LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles"));
                    then = then.with(TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame(DayOfWeek.THURSDAY)).withHour(13).withMinute(0).withSecond(0);
                    Duration duration = Duration.between(now, then);
                    long initialDelay = duration.getSeconds();

                    if (initialDelay < 0) {
                        initialDelay = Duration.between(now, then.with(TemporalAdjusters.next(DayOfWeek.THURSDAY)).withHour(13).withMinute(0)).getSeconds();
                    }

                    ScheduledExecutorService scheduledActivity = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
                    scheduledActivity.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
                                List<Message> messages = e.getChannel().getHistory().retrievePast(1).complete();
                                for (Message msg : messages) {
                                    if (!msg.getContentRaw().equalsIgnoreCase("Reminder")) {
                                        defaultChannel.sendTyping().queue();
                                        defaultChannel.sendMessage("Reminder").queue();
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            initialDelay,
                            TimeUnit.DAYS.toSeconds(7),
                            TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `ReadyEvent` to send a message to specific channel in your server.
For example, In your `ReadyEvent`:

```java
event.getJDA().getGuildById("Your Server ID").getTextChannelById("Your Discord Channel ID").sendMessage("Bot is ready!").queue();
```

or you can send it to your server's system channel by:

```java
event.getJDA().getGuildById("Your Server ID").getSystemChannel().sendMessage("Bot is ready!").queue();
```